# Adding a line break in xs:documentation for a xsd schema

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, newline

I am trying to create a xsd schema for Visual Studio and ModBuddy to make it easier and more user friendly to create the xml files for modding the game Civilization Beyond Earth.  My question is how do I add line breaks/ new lines into the documentation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="UNIT_PROTOTYPE">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            [TYPE] Is a Unique Name for your Unit which is defined in the UnitClass Table.  Example: UNIT_BERSERKER
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

I tried to use a simple line break which was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105118/how-to-format-xsd-documentation)

however it did not work, the line break < br/> did not show up in my xml tooltip and it didn't return the line to make a second line.

So my question is:  How do you add line breaks into xsd schema documentation?

roadmaster

Comment: Have you tried `<br />` or `<para>   </para>`?

Comment: Yes I had tried <br /> previously, just tried <para></para>  and retried <br /> and they don't do anything, however neither of them show up in the xml tooltip as text either, thanks for the suggestions though...

Comment: I guess you should have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279108/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-c-sharp-net-documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this functionality is not possible using Visual Studio and or ModBuddy, which is an extension of Visual Studio.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ff9e911-c651-402c-9ceb-9035943a7609/xml-intellisense-formatting-in-xsd?forum=xmlandnetfx

Thank you everyone who replied and tried to help.  maybe some day in the future Microsoft will add this functionality.

roadmaster

Answer (score 0):

There is a special syntax for line break in XML:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-line-ends

Can you try the following ?

<-- language: XML -->

```
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
        This is in first line.#xD#xA This is in second line.
    </xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't do anything either. just shows the single full line:  "This is a string value, Used in createing or modifying AnimationPaths.#xD#xA  Example:  ANIMATIONPATH_MOVE, the list of current Animation Paths are listed as examples that may be modified or overridden."